# Redis Client Windows Metro Apps

Tags: redis, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there any Redis client for Windows Metro Apps? The ones I have found are not compatible with the Windows 8.1 Framework, including all the ones listed in http://redis.io/clients#c.

Comment: You could always create a web service for connecting ro and sending the redis data to the metro app;

Comment: That is true but I lose the Pub/Sub feature of Redis, since with a web-service I had to keep polling it.